# NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() returning null at android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-manifest, ros

I'm new to Java programming and Android in general, but I'm trying to use the following code to get my network interface

```
try {
    Enumeration interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    List<String> ll = Collections.list(interfaces);
    Log.d("interfaces", "List elements: "+ll);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But whenever I try to run it, I get the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.Enumeration.hasMoreElements()' on a null object reference
```

I have already added both INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissions to the Android Manifest. What else should I do to make it work?

P.S. What I'm really trying to do is to run a class implemented by ros_java, but it was not working, and I found that the error was because of the null object returned by `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();`.

If you need any more info, just let me know.

UPDATE
I tried the same code in a phone and it threw no exception, but I really need it to work at the emulator.

Comment: Have you tried to configure a Network interface on the emulator ? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Comment: I didn't understand it clearly what you mean by configuring the network interface, is it the [network redirection] (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#redirection)?

Comment: I thought that the NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces would return me things like: wi-fi, ethernet and other types of connections that would be available to the machine, if so, aren't they already available when I start up the emulator?